# Set text as url in Magento 2 Grid table records

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid, url, uicomponent

I have a grid table that shows order id's only in text form, I want to change it into hyperlink format that redirect to order page based on the order id,
here's my grid:

```
        <column name="order_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Order ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```